# Logout URL in same window and in same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to logout a link in the same window and in the same tab that contains the page with the link.

When I try click logout a link by using window.open, then it opens in new tab—not in the same tab in the same window and the current page will not logout unless i refresh the pages.

ｃｏｄｅ：

```
+"<button class=\"withdraw\" onclick=\"window.open(\'/index/LogOut.html\')\">Logout</button>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `window.open`, you can set the `window.location.href` property which will caues the *current* window to navigate to the specified URL.

e.g.

`<button class="withdraw" onclick="window.location.href='/index/LogOut.html'">Logout</button>`